# IO error when contacting "/res/repositoryService

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I am trying to deploy a rule app to a Rule Execution Service configuration in Bluemix and I receive the following error: `IO error when contacting "/res/repositoryService"`.

How can I fix this error?

The Bluemix URL is HTTPS and I have set the IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable to `-Dilog.rules.res.allowSelfSignedCertificate=true`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if you are behind a firewall? If so, please configure it to allow connecting to the RES URL.